# iPhone 6s storage usage

Tags: mail.app, storage, iphone

I want to ask you why in the usage section of iPhone 6s on iOS 9.2 it says I have 2.6 GB in Mail. However, I have deleted all inbox, sent, trash, etc. There is nothing in Mail.

How do I get the storage in the usage section to empty this Mail?

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be graphical 'bug'. If you are sure that mail is empty, you can always try to reboot/hard reset device and if the issue is still there, then take a iTunes backup and restore device. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184 should be good article for this troubleshooting step.

Comment: Still same... How could i do? 